# XMPP chat : Candy won't work with Ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, candy

I want to setup a web chat client. I decided to use [Candy](https://candy-chat.github.io/candy/#underthehood). The XMPP server I'm using is Ejabberd. My Ejabberd server is local. The URL is :

```
http://localhost:5280/
```

Users are defined like this :

```
user@localhost
```

The thing is I can't connect to this server using Candy out of the box while I can connect to it with simple strophejs functions on my phone.

I compared the packets that were sent to the server and they are exactly the same :

- On my phone using Wireshark :

[image]

- The console log when I'm connecting with Candy :

[image]

The screen is pending on "Connecting..."

What can be the reason that I can't connect to the server ? Is there something I have to configure in ejabberd.cfg ?

Thanks for help

Comment: nevermind, my Candy.init had a bad url , I changed it to : http://localhost:5280/http-bind/

Comment: Indeed, /http-bind is correct URL for bosh support.

Answer (score 1):

The default URL for BOSH on ejabberd is `/http-bind`

When configuring your BOSH client you should point to that directory on the correct web URL, not the ejabberd service root.

Using `http://example.net:5280/http-bind` as BOSH URL in your Web client configuration should work.